# respondToSwipeGesture in many scenes

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit

I'm trying to add a swipe gesture to scenes inherited from the main  scene(GameScene)

```
extension GameScene {

    class Scene1: GameScene {

        override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

            let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
            swipeRight.direction = .right
            view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

            let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
            swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down
            view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

            let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
            swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
            view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

            let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
            swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
            view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
        }
    }
    class Scene2: GameScene {

        override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

            let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
            swipeRight.direction = .right
            view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

            let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
            swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down
            view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

            let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
            swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up
            view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

            let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.respondToSwipeGesture))
            swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left
            view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
        }
    }
}
```

And every time I'm must to write this code other and other again in all scenes. Maybe, there is another way out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you read your code, you will see that you never add a gesture to a scene, you add it to a view.  Now ask yourself, what other object do you have will have access to the view?  The answer, is the view controller.  This is where you want to be placing your gesture code.

Comment: what?  that makes no sense

Comment: var  scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768))
     func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
             let view = self.view as! SKView        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: scene, action:  #selector(scene.respondToSwipeGesture(gesture:)))
        swipeDown.direction = .down
        view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

Comment: why would you do `scene.respondToSwipeGesture`?

Comment: I add this code in GameViewController but Xcode don't see this

Comment: Your code is wrong, you want to put all your gesture functions into the view controller